# How to make segmentation mask larger?

Tags: python, deep-learning, image-segmentation, scikit-image

I have built a segmentation model to segment certain object's inside my images.  I want to be able to enlarge my predicted segmentation mask by specified number of pixel (e.g, ndim = 10 pixels) and I am wondering what would be the best and efficient way to do it.

Currently,  I am using skimage built-in function of `view_as_windows` and it takes around 30 sec per mask to enlarge it.

I pad my image with ndim-1 and I specify the `window_shape` to be (ndim, ndim)

then I return the new mask as follows:

```
new_x = np.pad(x, ((pad_size, pad_size), (pad_size, pad_size)), 'constant', constant_values=(0, 0))
new_x = view_as_windows(new_x, window_shape)
new_x = new_x.max(axis=(2,3))
new_x = new_x[half_pad:-half_pad, half_pad:-half_pad]
```

Is there a better (more efficient way) to do it?

Comment: Questions in the abstract aren't a good fit for SO. A [minimal, reproducible, and complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help you get an answer.

Comment: @Ouroborus can you reopen the question? or I should repost it?